# Xamarin Firebase Cloud messaging request token

Tags: android, xamarin, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to know which is the best way to check if a `firebaseInstanceId` request for a token has been sent successfully. If I request a new token without a connection or airplane mode I don't get any exception or error.

This is my code to request a new token:

```
//get token 
var instanceID = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance;
instanceID.DeleteInstanceId();
var iid1 = instanceID.Token;
var iid2 = instanceID.GetToken("my_sender_id",FirebaseMessaging.InstanceIdScope);
```

Comment: How did you integrated FCM in Xamarin? Wich plugin did you used?

Comment: the official xamarin.firebase packages

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with Xamarin, but why not just keep a local variable for the old token, then check if it's the same value for `getToken()`? Wouldn't that work?

Comment: Could you please debug to see what is returned when Internet is not available or in airplane mode?

Comment: did you checked this link https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/tree/master/firebase-messaging/samples

Comment: @AL. I need to know at the first start up of the app.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT If I debug it instanceId.Token and GetToken() has never been called when connection is unavailable

Comment: A possible solution could be to do it only when connection is available. When phone is offline set a broadcast receiver on connectivity change and do it when is online. Because without the refreshedToken I am unable to send notification with firebase console

Comment: Ok I get what I was missing. I thought the first token wasn't invalid and I must refresh it in order to get notification. Instead the first token is valid, so even if I don't refresh it because there is no connection, I am still able to use it and to get notification with the current token.